# Как отправить изображение вместе с Html в C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, веб-программирование

У меня есть WEB-сервер, созданный на C#, он основан на TcpListener и выглядит всё это так(работа с клиентом)

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: text/html\nContent-Length:"+Properties.Resources.page.Length+"\n\n"+Properties.Resources.page);
client.GetStream().Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
client.Close();
```

А в page.html в ресурсах есть картинка, подключённая через `<img src="img1">`,
но программа при отправке не видит картинку.

Comment: `WEB-сервер, созданный на C#, он основан на TcpListener` чем вас asp.net не устроил?

Comment: мне кажется не удобным

Comment: Вам же надо веб сервер написать? Asp.net это лучшее, что может предложить майкрософт для написания веб сервера. С tcplistener вы точно намучаетесь

Comment: спасибо, послушаю ваш совет.